# Wifi switch takes wlan0 down, but doesn't bring it back up. Found a possible cause and solution just need to know how to apply it

Tags: wireless, wpa-supplicant, rfkill

I've got an old acre extensa laptop with a wifi button which takes the wifi down ok.  When pressing it again to enable it I get the following log:

```
Jun 12 12:11:58 digit-laptop wpa_supplicant[14223]: rfkill: WLAN unblocked
Jun 12 12:11:58 digit-laptop wpa_supplicant[14223]: Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Operation not possible due to RF-kill
Jun 12 12:11:59 digit-laptop wpa_supplicant[14223]: rfkill: WLAN unblocked
```

My assumption is that wpa_supplicant, or the invoking script is trying to bring the interface up before the hard block is removed and wpa_supplicant reports it.

```
ifdown -a
ifup -a
```

fixes everything.

So, my solution(s) are to either find the mapping between the button and the script, edit the script to add a delay, or edit a config somewhere to do the same for wpa_supplicant or....Im not sure where or what I should be looking to edit to correctly solve this issue.

Or this is already answered but I've looked and looked and the wood is hiding in the trees somewhere, so, Im asking for help....please :)

Ive verified that the soft and hard blocks are added and removed after button presses it just seems to be the order of events that causes the problem.

Pressing the button quickly, results in the orange light coming on but very odd behaviour, having to issue several ifdown -a commands in order to successfully run an ifup -a command.

Im not to concerned with the robustness of the switch, I can handle pressing it once and waiting before the urge to press it again.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help...or reading my question at least :)

Cheers,
Twokay

Comment: Further investigation shows that the wifi button does not run if down -a or any equivalent, so wpa_supplicant is just reporting the wifi drop...I guess. So if I'd don't run ifdown -a before ifup -a the network doesn't come back.  I'm having some success running ifup then hitting the switch, so my question has changed a bit now to how do I intercept the wifi switch so I can run ifdown or ifup depending on the hard block state of the interface?

Comment: Seems I'll be answering my own post here...lots of people are asking about this and I think ultimately they just ant their button to work without issuing commands.  On more further investigation, you can monitor the state of the wireless adapter using the 'rfkill event' command. So just run this command at startup before your link comes up and have a script monitor the output.  When you see a button press find out what interface, the state and issue ifdown, ifup accordingly.  I don't understand why this isn't working in a brand new linux distort it's not rocket science and seems common place??